# What is the easiest way of deleting all my blobstore data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, task-queue

What is your best way to remove all of the blob from blobstore? I'm using Python.

I have quite a lot of blobs and I'd like to delete them all.  I'm 
currently doing the following:

```
class deleteBlobs(webapp.RequestHandler): 
    def get(self): 
        all = blobstore.BlobInfo.all(); 
        more = (all.count()>0) 
        blobstore.delete(all); 
        if more: 
            taskqueue.add(url='/deleteBlobs',method='GET');
```

Which seems to be using tons of CPU and (as far as I can tell) doing 
nothing useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the query object to the delete method, which will iterate over it fetching it in batches, then submit a single enormous delete. This is inefficient because it requires multiple fetches, and won't work if you have more results than you can fetch in the available time or with the available memory. The task will either complete once and not require chaining at all, or more likely, fail repeatedly, since it can't fetch every blob at once.

Also, calling `count` executes the query just to determine the count, which is a waste of time since you're going to try fetching the results anyway.

Instead, you should fetch results in batches using `fetch`, and delete each batch. Use cursors to set the next batch and avoid the need for the query to iterate over all the 'tombstoned' records before finding the first live one, and ideally, delete multiple batches per task, using a timer to determine when you should stop and chain the next task.

Answer (score 7):

I use this approach:

```
import datetime
import logging
import re
import urllib

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.api import users


class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello. Blobstore is being purged.\n\n')
        try:
            query = blobstore.BlobInfo.all()

            index = 0

            to_delete = []
            blobs = query.fetch(400)
            if len(blobs) > 0:
                for blob in blobs:
                    blob.delete()
                    index += 1

            hour = datetime.datetime.now().time().hour
            minute = datetime.datetime.now().time().minute
            second = datetime.datetime.now().time().second
            self.response.out.write(str(index) + ' items deleted at ' + str(hour) + ':' + str(minute) + ':' + str(second))
            if index == 400:
                self.redirect("/purge")

        except Exception, e:
            self.response.out.write('Error is: ' + repr(e) + '\n')
            pass

APP = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [
        ('/purge', IndexHandler),
    ],
    debug=True)

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(APP)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My experience is that more than 400 blobs at once will fail, so I let it reload for every 400. I tried `blobstore.delete(query.fetch(400))`, but I think there's a bug right now. Nothing happened at all, and nothing was deleted.

Comment: worked for me. a few remarks : 1/ the output is only visible once the page has ended loading, in my case this only happened at the end of the last redirect (the last 400 query). 2/ i still had a couple of http 500 errors, so i would just reload the page whenever it did, and it would keep on deleting the blobs.

Comment: You don't need to check `if len(blobs) > 0` before iterating over blobs. In Python it is safe to try to iterate over an empty collection.

Comment: You will only have problem if its None, as @Attila mentioned its is safe to iterate empty collections. You can be safe though in any case by `if blobs:` since python will return false for 0, empty collection or None.